# Get currentuserinfo firstname and lastname

Tags: user-meta

I am trying to insert the user firstname and last name into the database whilst processing a woocommerce order. I have managed to get two empty fields into the database where I need them however i am struggling to get the users first name and last name to post. Below is the code i have so far, would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

```
// add user firstname
    if ( ! $order_data['user_firstname'] ) {
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $order_data['user_firstname'] = get_currentuserinfo($current_user->user_firstname);
        } else {
            $order_data['user_firstname'] = 0;
        }
    }

    // add user surname
    if ( ! $order_data['user_surname'] ) {
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $order_data['user_surname'] = get_currentuserinfo($current_user->user_lastname);
        } else {
            $order_data['user_surname'] = 0;
        }
    }
```

This is the complete contents of the file. Everything works apart from populating first name and last name

```
/**
* Main model class for all bookings, this handles all the data
*/
class WC_Booking {

    /** @public int */
    public $id;

    /** @public string */
    public $booking_date;

    /** @public string */
    public $start;

    /** @public string */
    public $end;

    /** @public bool */
    public $all_day;

    /** @public string */
    public $modified_date;

    /** @public object */
    public $post;

    /** @public int */
    public $product_id;

    /** @public object */
    public $product;

    /** @public int */
    public $order_id;

    /** @public object */
    public $order;

    /** @public int */
    public $customer_id;

    /** @public string */
    public $status;

    /** @public array - contains all post meta values for this booking */
    public $custom_fields;

    /** @public bool */
    public $populated;

    /** @private array - used to temporarily hold order data for new bookings */
    private $order_data;

    /**
     * Constructor, possibly sets up with post or id belonging to existing booking
     * or supplied with an array to construct a new booking
     * @param int/array/obj $booking_data
     */
    public function __construct( $booking_data = false ) {
        $populated = false;

        if ( is_array( $booking_data ) ) {
            $this->order_data = $booking_data;
            $populated = false;
        } else if ( is_int( intval( $booking_data ) ) && 0 < $booking_data ) {
            $populated = $this->populate_data( $booking_data );
        } else if ( is_object( $booking_data ) && isset( $booking_data->ID ) ) {
            $this->post = $booking_data;
            $populated = $this->populate_data( $booking_data->ID );
        }

        $this->populated = $populated;
    }

    /**
     * Actual create for the new booking belonging to an order
     * @param string Status for new order
     */
    public function create( $status = 'unpaid' ) {
        $this->new_booking( $status, $this->order_data );
        $this->schedule_events();
    }

    /**
     * Schedule events for this booking
     */
    public function schedule_events() {
        switch ( get_post_status( $this->id ) ) {
            case "paid" :
                if ( $this->start ) {
                    wp_schedule_single_event( strtotime( '-' . absint( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_remind_before_days', 1 ) ) . ' day', $this->start ), 'wc-booking-reminder', array( $this->id ) );
                }
                if ( $this->end ) {
                    wp_schedule_single_event( $this->end, 'wc-booking-complete', array( $this->id ) );
                }
            break;
            default :
                wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'wc-booking-reminder', array( $this->id ) );
                wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'wc-booking-complete', array( $this->id ) );
            break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Makes the new booking belonging to an order
     * @param string $status The status for this new booking
     * @param array $order_data Array with all the new order data
     */
    private function new_booking( $status, $order_data ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $order_data = wp_parse_args( $order_data, array(
            'user_id'           => 0,
            'resource_id'       => '',
            'product_id'        => '',
            'order_item_id'     => '',
            'persons'           => array(),
            'cost'              => '',
            'start_date'        => '',
            'end_date'          => '',
            'all_day'           => 0,
            'parent_id'         => 0,
        ) );

        // Get parent data
        if ( $order_data['parent_id'] ) {
            if ( ! $order_data['order_item_id'] )
                $order_data['order_item_id'] = get_post_meta( $order_data['parent_id'], '_booking_order_item_id', true );

            if ( ! $order_data['user_id'] )
                $order_data['user_id'] = get_post_meta( $order_data['parent_id'], '_booking_customer_id', true );
        }

        // Get order ID from order item
        if ( $order_data['order_item_id'] )
            $order_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT order_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items WHERE order_item_id = %d", $order_data['order_item_id'] ) );
        else
            $order_id = 0;

        $booking_data = array(
            'post_type'   => 'wc_booking',
            'post_title'  => sprintf( __( 'Booking &ndash; %s', 'woocommerce-bookings' ), strftime( _x( '%b %d, %Y @ %I:%M %p', 'Booking date parsed by strftime', 'woocommerce-bookings' ) ) ),
            'post_status' => $status,
            'ping_status' => 'closed',
            'post_parent' => $order_id
        );

        $this->id = wp_insert_post( $booking_data );

        // Setup the required data for the current user
        if ( ! $order_data['user_id'] ) {
            if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                $order_data['user_id'] = get_current_user_id();
            } else {
                $order_data['user_id'] = 0;
            }
        }

    $user_info = wp_get_current_user();

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $order_data['user_firstname'] = $user_info->user_firstname;
    // add user surname
    $order_data['user_surname'] = $user_info->user_lastname;
}

        // Convert booking start and end to requried format
        if ( is_numeric( $order_data['start_date'] ) ) {
            // Convert timestamp
            $order_data['start_date'] = date( 'YmdHis', $order_data['start_date'] );
            $order_data['end_date']   = date( 'YmdHis', $order_data['end_date'] );
        } else {
            $order_data['start_date'] = date( 'YmdHis', strtotime( $order_data['start_date'] ) );
            $order_data['end_date']   = date( 'YmdHis', strtotime( $order_data['end_date'] ) );
        }

        $meta_args = array(
            '_booking_order_item_id' => $order_data['order_item_id'],
            '_booking_product_id'    => $order_data['product_id'],
            '_booking_resource_id'   => $order_data['resource_id'],
            '_booking_persons'       => $order_data['persons'],
            '_booking_cost'          => $order_data['cost'],
            '_booking_start'         => $order_data['start_date'],
            '_booking_end'           => $order_data['end_date'],
            '_booking_all_day'       => intval( $order_data['all_day'] ),
            '_booking_parent_id'     => $order_data['parent_id'],
            '_booking_customer_id'   => $order_data['user_id'],
            // hp extras
            '_booking_customer_firstname'   => $order_data['user_firstname'],
            '_booking_customer_surname'   => $order_data['user_surname'],
        );

        foreach ( $meta_args as $key => $value ) {
            update_post_meta( $this->id, $key, $value );
        }

        do_action( 'woocommerce_new_booking', $this->id );
    }

    /**
     * Populate the data with the id of the booking provided
     * Will query for the post belonging to this booking and store it
     * @param int $booking_id
     */
    public function populate_data( $booking_id ) {
        if ( ! isset( $this->post ) ) {
            $post = get_post( $booking_id );
        }

        if ( is_object( $post ) ) {
            // We have the post object belonging to this booking, now let's populate
            $this->id            = $post->ID;
            $this->booking_date  = $post->post_date;
            $this->modified_date = $post->post_modified;
            $this->customer_id   = $post->post_author;
            $this->custom_fields = get_post_meta( $this->id );
            $this->status        = $post->post_status;
            $this->order_id      = $post->post_parent;

            // Define the data we're going to load: Key => Default value
            $load_data = array(
                'product_id'  => '',
                'resource_id' => '',
                'persons'     => array(),
                'cost'        => '',
                'start'       => '',
                'customer_id' => '',
                'end'         => '',
                'all_day'     => 0,
                'parent_id'   => 0,
                'user_firstname' => '',
                'user_surname' => '',

            );

            // Load the data from the custom fields (with prefix for this plugin)
            $meta_prefix = '_booking_';

            foreach ( $load_data as $key => $default ) {
                if ( isset( $this->custom_fields[ $meta_prefix . $key ][0] ) && $this->custom_fields[ $meta_prefix . $key ][0] !== '' ) {
                    $this->$key = maybe_unserialize( $this->custom_fields[ $meta_prefix . $key ][0] );
                } else {
                    $this->$key = $default;
                }
            }

            // Start and end date converted to timestamp
            $this->start = strtotime( $this->start );
            $this->end   = strtotime( $this->end );

            // Save the post object itself for future reference
            $this->post = $post;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Will change the booking status once the order is paid for
     * @return bool
     */
    public function paid() {
        $current_status = $this->status;

        if ( $this->populated && in_array( $current_status, array( 'unpaid', 'confirmed' ) ) ) {
            $this->update_status( 'paid' );
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Set the new status for this booking
     * @param string $status
     * @return bool
     */
    public function update_status( $status ) {
        $current_status   = $this->get_status( true );
        $allowed_statuses = array( 'unpaid', 'pending', 'confirmed', 'paid', 'cancelled', 'complete' );

        if ( $this->populated ) {
            if ( in_array( $status, $allowed_statuses ) ) {
                wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $this->id, 'post_status' => $status ) );

                // Reschedule cron
                $this->schedule_events();

                // Trigger actions
                do_action( 'woocommerce_booking_' . $current_status . '_to_' . $status, $this->id );
                do_action( 'woocommerce_booking_' . $status, $this->id );

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the status of this booking
     * @param Bool to ask for pretty status name (if false)
     * @return String of the booking status
     */
    public function get_status( $raw = true ) {
        if ( $this->populated ) {
            if ( $raw ) {
                return $this->status;
            } else {
                $status_object = get_post_status_object( $this->status );
                return $status_object->label;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the id of this booking
     * @return Id of the booking or false if booking is not populated
     */
    public function get_id() {
        if ( $this->populated ) {
            return $this->id;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the product ID for the booking
     * @return int or false if booking is not populated
     */
    public function get_product_id() {
        if ( $this->populated ) {
            return $this->product_id;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the object of the order corresponding to this booking
     * @return Product object or false if booking is not populated
     */
    public function get_product() {
        if ( ! isset( $this->product ) || empty( $this->product ) ) {
            if ( $this->populated && $this->product_id ) {
                $this->product = get_product( $this->product_id );
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return $this->product;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the object of the order corresponding to this booking
     * @return Order object or false if booking is not populated
     */
    public function get_order() {
        if ( empty( $this->order ) ) {
            if ( $this->populated && ! empty( $this->order_id ) && 'shop_order' === get_post_type( $this->order_id ) ) {
                $this->order = new WC_Order( $this->order_id );
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return $this->order;
    }

    /**
     * Return if all day event
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function is_all_day() {
        if ( $this->populated ) {
            if ( $this->all_day ) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * See if this booking is booked on said date
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function is_booked_on_day( $block_start, $block_end ) {
        if ( $this->populated ) {
            $loop_date        = $this->start;
            $multiday_booking = date( 'Y-m-d', $this->start ) < date( 'Y-m-d', $this->end );

            if ( $multiday_booking ) {
                if ( date( 'YmdHi', $block_end ) > date( 'YmdHi', $this->start ) || date( 'YmdHi', $block_start ) < date( 'YmdHi', $this->end ) ) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            while ( $loop_date <= $this->end ) {
                if ( date( 'Y-m-d', $loop_date ) === date( 'Y-m-d', $block_start ) ) {
                    return true;
                }
                $loop_date = strtotime( "+1 day", $loop_date );
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Returns booking start date
     * @return string Date formatted via date_i18n
     */
    public function get_start_date( $date_format = null, $time_format = null ) {
        if ( $this->populated && ! empty( $this->start ) ) {
            if ( is_null( $date_format ) ) {
                $date_format = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_date_format', 'M jS Y' );
            }
            if ( is_null( $time_format ) ) {
                $time_format = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_time_format', ', g:ia' );
            }
            if ( $this->is_all_day() ) {
                return date_i18n( $date_format, $this->start );
            } else {
                return date_i18n( $date_format . $time_format, $this->start );
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Returns booking end date
     * @return string Date formatted via date_i18n
     */
    public function get_end_date( $date_format = null, $time_format = null ) {
        if ( $this->populated && ! empty( $this->end ) ) {
            if ( is_null( $date_format ) ) {
                $date_format = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_date_format', 'M jS Y' );
            }
            if ( is_null( $time_format ) ) {
                $time_format = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_time_format', ', g:ia' );
            }
            if ( $this->is_all_day() ) {
                return date_i18n( $date_format, $this->end );
            } else {
                return date_i18n( $date_format . $time_format, $this->end );
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Returns information about the customer of this order
     * @return array containing customer information
     */
    public function get_customer() {
        if ( $this->populated ) {
            $order = $this->get_order();

            if ( $order )
                return (object) array(
                    'name'    => trim( $order->billing_first_name . ' ' . $order->billing_last_name ),
                    'email'   => $order->billing_email,
                    'user_id' => $order->customer_user,
                );
            elseif ( $this->customer_id ) {
                $user = get_user_by( 'id', $this->customer_id );

                return (object) array(
                    'name'    => $user->display_name,
                    'email'   => $user->user_email,
                    'user_id' => $this->customer_id
                );
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Returns if persons are enabled/needed for the booking product
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function has_persons() {
        return $this->get_product()->has_persons();
    }

    /**
     * Returns if resources are enabled/needed for the booking product
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function has_resources() {
        return $this->get_product()->has_resources();
    }

    /**
     * Return a array with the booking persons.
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_persons() {
        return (array) $this->persons;
    }

    /**
     * Return the amount of persons for this booking.
     * @return int
     */
    public function get_persons_total() {
        return array_sum( $this->get_persons() );
    }

    /**
     * Get the resource id
     * @return int
     */
    public function get_resource_id() {
        return absint( $this->resource_id );
    }

    /**
     * Get the resource/type for this booking if applicable.
     * @return bool|object WP_Post
     */
    public function get_resource() {
        $resource_id = $this->get_resource_id();

        if ( ! $resource_id || ! $this->get_product() )
            return false;

        return $this->get_product()->get_resource( $resource_id );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [`get_currentuserinfo`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo) in a wrong way because you are passing parameters that this functions doesn't accept and you expect that the functions return directly what you want. `get_currentuserinfo` doesn't accept any parameter, returns a WP User object and require the global `$current_user` var.

Anyway, I prefer to use `wp_get_current_user()` in order to avoid working directly with globals:

```
$user_info = wp_get_current_user();

if ( ! $order_data['user_firstname'] ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $order_data['user_firstname'] = $user_info->user_firstname;
    } else {
        $order_data['user_firstname'] = 0;
    }
}

// add user surname
if ( ! $order_data['user_surname'] ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $order_data['user_surname'] = $user_info->user_lastname;
    } else {
        $order_data['user_surname'] = 0;
    }
}
```

And in your code, you are populating the array `$order_data` with default values for each key. After that, you check, for example, `if ( ! $order_data['user_surname'] )`; because `$order_data['user_surname']` was filled with default values, all the code inside that `if` statement won't be executed. You should leave the code in this way (default values was already set, so it will modified only for logged in users):

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

    $user_info = wp_get_current_user();

    $order_data['user_firstname'] = $user_info->user_firstname;
    // add user surname
    $order_data['user_surname'] = $user_info->user_lastname;

}
```

You still say that the oly thing is not working is the name and last name. But you can verify yourself that it is working:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

    $user_info = wp_get_current_user();

    $order_data['user_firstname'] = $user_info->user_firstname;
    // add user surname
    $order_data['user_surname'] = $user_info->user_lastname;

}
var_dump($order_data);
```

You will see how de dump data inludes the name and lastname if you are logged in. Please, debug the `$order_data`.

Comment: This still returned an empty field within the database. I have edited the question to inlclude a link to the complete file incase that helps?

Comment: Please, include all the relevant code in the question, not through thrid party services, for future users that may can here looking for the same help.

Comment: I've seen your code and edited the answer. Please see it and please add the relevant code in the question and not through third party services.

Comment: I replaced my code with the second snippet you provided however this has also not worked? I still get an empty field within the database. I will include the full file in the question now also.

Comment: I'm sorry but until you include all the relevant code in the question I'm not going to continue investigating where the problem is. And yes, **it is working for the question made about geting current user name and last name**, but it seems that you have more problems. Plus the `$order_data` checks you posted in the question, you have a lot more in your code. just follow my advice about the default values and that uneeded chekings you are making and that are causing you the problems.

Comment: I have updated the question with the full contents of the file. This all works apart from the first name and last name. The field in the database is being created however no data is being populated within the database. Thanks, Ben

Comment: Please, debug the content of `$order_data`; for example using `var_dump` as suggested in my answer (last edition).

Comment: It is working now. I tried it with another user and it turns out i had only given the user account a billing first name and last name not a standard first name and last name. So there was no data to put into the DB. having added a normal first name and last name it is working. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can get current user info by calling `get_currentuserinfo()` function and global `$current_user` array.

So here will be the changes in your code.

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

// add user firstname
if ( ! $order_data['user_firstname'] ) {
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $order_data['user_firstname'] = $current_user->user_firstname;
  } else {
    $order_data['user_firstname'] = 0;
  }
}

// add user surname
if ( ! $order_data['user_surname'] ) {
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $order_data['user_surname'] = $current_user->user_lastname;
  } else {
    $order_data['user_surname'] = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: This still returned an empty field within the database. I have edited the question to inlclude a link to the complete file incase that helps?